# Silverlight: Message box prompting user to enter some text?

Tags: silverlight, messagebox

I'm using Silverlight 4. I'd like a message box that prompts the user to enter some text. Is this possible? So far, it looks like the only option is to ask the user to click a button.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new [Child Window](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/29/silverlight-3-s-new-child-windows.aspx) in visual studio and build your input form in that child window.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project http://silverlightmsgbox.codeplex.com/. It presents a simple but presentable implementation of several useful message boxes i.e. confirm, error, info, user input, etc. and might be helpful to you. Good luck.